# git: how to do a commit so that the current branch is the same as another branch?

Tags: git, version-control

Suppose I have two branches, `A` and `B`, and they all diverge from `master`

```
master --> commit1 --> commit2 --> A
   |
   |-----> commit3 --> commit4 --> B
```

Now I want to do a commit(`commit5` in the following diagram) on `A`, so that the code on `A` is the same as the one on `B`.

```
master --> commit1 --> commit2 --> A --> commit5 --> A`(same as B)
   |
   |-----> commit3 --> commit4 --> B
```

How to do that?

Comment: Show us what the final branch looks like.

Answer (score 1):

You can [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) the commit in Branch `A`:

```
$ git checkout A
$ git cherry-pick commit3Id
$ git cherry-pick commit4Id
```

To remove `commit1` and `commit2` from branch A, you have to run the [git-revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) command as follows:

```
$ git checkout A
$ git revert commit1Id
$ git revert commit2Id
```

Comment: Wouldn't `commit1` and `commit2` still exist in branch A?

Comment: This is not my interpretation of the OP.  You should explain your logic.

Comment: @Searene it would be there, to revert `commit1` and `commit2`, check updated answer.

Comment: Don't use `cherry-pick`. You'll regret when you want to `merge` the branches.

Comment: This is too complicated. I would like to use one or two commands to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider if merging `B` into `A` is what you want. A merge will by default combine the changes instead of making the tree of `A` match `B`.

```
git checkout A
git merge B
```

It's hard to tell if this is an XY question where you are asking for an intermediate step which you *think* is what is needed, or if it is actually what you need. A merge or a rebase (if altering history is ok) is probably the sane way to go about this, if what you want is to bring one branch up-to-date with the other.

---

If you indeed prefer to do this without creating a merge commit and without rebasing, there are various ways to go about it.

To record an commit on branch `A` that will add the necessary changes so that it resembles the project state in branch `B` without `B`'s commit history, this is one way:

```
git checkout A
git read-tree B
git commit -m 'Reflect the state of B'
```

Note that the working directory will still have the old state after this. You can use `git reset --hard` followed by manual removal of any untracked files. `git clean` is another option for removing untracked files.

More info on `git read-tree` at [man git-read-tree](https://gitirc.eu/git-read-tree.html).

As always, be sure to **have a backup** before entering dragon land.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to make A the exact same as B (getting rid of the commits on A and adding the commits that are on B), there are a couple of options. Both are destructive, because no matter how you do it you'll have to get rid of those two commits. I'd recommend creating another branch on A so you have something with that history at least.

## Option A: Reset the commits

```
git checkout A          # in case you aren't on A already
git reset --hard master # delete all commits and changes on A
git rebase -i B         # rebase on B, inheriting its two commits
```

## Option B: Delete the branch

```
git checkout B     # Move to branch B so you can inherit B's commits
git branch -D A    # Delete branch A
git checkout -b A  # Create branch A while on B's commits
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below commands to achieve what you need:

```
git checkout A
git checkout B -- .
git commit -m 'content same as branch B'
```